# Get all pages and posts with get_pages() or get_posts()

Tags: get-posts

Trying to get all posts (with all I mean all pages, posts and posts from custom post types).

Is this possible? The documentation says I can only pass a string as `post_type` so how can I get all pages and custom post types?

Example where custom post type is called `project`

```
$args = array(
    'exclude'      => $inclPages,
    'post_type'    => 'pages,project',
    'title_li'     => __(''),
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order'
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) does not work with posts or post types that is not hierarchical like pages, so if your post type is hierarchical like posts, it would not work

> This function can also retrieve other post types using the 'post_type' parameter, but the type must be hierarchical like pages, or the function will return false.

If you need all post types to be returned, ie all `post`, `page` and custom post types, just pass `any` to `post_type` in either [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), the choice is up to you

Comment: "any" did the trick! thanks a lot! also for the question edit.. my english is getting better :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked :-)

Answer (score 8):

Why not use `WP_Query` instead. Like this.

```
$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => $inclPages,
    'post_type'    => array( 'page', 'project' )
    'orderby'      => 'menu_order'
);
$pages = new WP_Query ( $args );
```

WP_Query accepts wide range of parameters. And also post_type array.

Comment: never used WP_Query before